# Confused about VB/C# conversion with event handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I've used just about every conversion tool out there to convert a snippet of [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) to C#. Aside from some differences in conversion, the one thing that I am having trouble grasping is event handler conversion. Looking at some pure C# code, I see things like this:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    ...
}
```

which looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.onprerender.aspx), raises the PreRender event. OK. Now, taking some VB.NET code:

```
Private Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, 
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
....
EndSub
```

which handles the same PreRender event and translating it with a conversion tool ([DeveloperFusion seemed to give the cleanest conversion of the Event Handler)](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) gave this result:

```
public class MyClass : UserControl
{
    private void Page_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
        PreRender += Page_PreRender;
    }
}
```

Being new to this, my main question is whether or not the original (or pure) C# code first listed above is basically the same as the converted C# code (other than maybe with the `object sender` portion)? And if not a brief explanation would be much appreciated.

Essentially, I am just wondering whether the `PreRender += Page_PreRender;` portion is superfluous.

Comment: Your first c# code block is not raising the event, it is only the event handler, the event handler will still be wired up somewhere. The += in the last block is wiring up the event to the handler, which is the equivelant of the VB.NET handles keyword

Comment: @chriswarner Hmmm, you're right. Sorry, my confusion lies with a class file and a code-behind. However, would the converted code be right for a class file? I.e., is the wiring up in the converted file the "best practice"?

Comment: @chris: No, the first C# code block doesn't have an event handler, it isn't using events or delegates at all.

Comment: @Ben: Sorry, yes you are right I was presuming it was an event handler due to the name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first C# code block presentes an *override* of the base classes' `OnPreRender` function, while the second is an event handler to the `PreRender` event.

Yes, they are different, but functionally they are more-or-less equivialent, because as you mentioned the base classes `OnPreRender` function will fire the `PreRender` event.

Essentially it represents two ways to accomplish the same thing, and the mechanism you choose is mostly a question of semantics. I say mostly because there may exist explicit reasons to choose one method over the other, but if you aren't aware of any, just choose one.

I prefer the override myself, as you typically use events to broadcast notifications to external listeners rather than to derived instances of an object.

The `PreRender += Page_PreRender` is not superfluous in your example, as it is required to hookup the event handler when you are using that mechanism. The VB version you posted is implemented using events rather that an override, so the conversion is correct. The "wire-up" for these events are implicit in VB.net, so you won't find an equivalent statement in the VB version.

Comment: Thanks for making sense of this. My confusion also lies in seeing C# class files using `OnInit` and `OnLoad` when inheriting (i.e., `MyClass : MyBase`). So this clarifies things a bit more for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the `PreRender += Page_PreRender;` portion superfluous?

No - that code is C#'s way of assigning the event handler, which is done in VB with the `Handles Me.PreRender` clause.

Comment: "my main question is whether or not the original (or pure) C# code first listed above is basically the same as the converted C# code"

Answer (score 1):

> Being a n00b, my main question is whether or not the original (or
>   pure) C# code first listed above is basically the same as the
>   converted C# code.

Yes, the conversion tool is **right**!

---

**Explanation**

VB.NET's `Handles` is the equivalent to `PreRender += Page_PreRender;`.

`Handles` basically does the exact same thing in the background; adding an eventhandler.

So **Codesnippet #1** and **Codesnippet #2** are the same, except that you need to manage the handler by yourself in #2 (Like removing the handler if the Windows Form gets disposed).

**Codesnippet #1 (VB.NET)**

```
Private Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, 
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
....
End Sub
```

**Codesnippet #2 (VB.NET)**

```
AddHandler Me.PreRender, AddressOf Page_PreRender
```

So obviously, no converted code is superfluous.

Comment: "my main question is whether or not the original (or pure) C# code first listed above is basically the same as the converted C# code"

Answer (score 1):

The conversion was done correctly, but it is **not** equivalent to the original C#:

> which looking at MSDN, **raises** the PreRender event.

The original code is not a handler, it's an invoker. `OnPreRender` is called to raise `PreRender`. If the VB code raised `PreRender` in `Page_PreRender`, it would lead to infinite recursion.

The overridable "On[event name]" pattern is used to allow subclasses to "handle" events, but it's not the same as a handler. The call to `base`/`MyBase` is what actually raises the event, so essentially by overriding one of these methods you're forcing an action to occur completely before or after (depending on where you call the base) all event handlers are invoked.